# Cross Reference Column A Sheet 1 w/ Column A Sheet 2 to give column c,d,e

Tags: excel, if-statement, indexing, excel-formula, vlookup

**Part 1:**

Cross Reference Column A Sheet 1 to find a matching value on Column A Sheet 2, and then fill in corresponding Column B, C, D Values from Sheet 2 for Sheet 1.

I have 2 sheets:

Sheet 1: Company & Representative
Sheet 2: Company & Client first name, Client Last Name, Client Email

I want to match to put in new columns on Sheet 1 that have the client first name, last name, and email based on the company matching ( they do not match by cell #).

Does anyone have any advice on how to do this? I've got about 2000 and know there must be a better way than manual.

**Part 2:**

Is it possible to use a similar formula to populate paragraph text in another column if the company name contains certain text or letters? Say the company titles are various and long but each contains adjectives that can help distinguish their industry or years of experience, then is it possible to make another column including 10+ possible conditions to fill out different paragraphs depending on the conditions met?

So for example have company names in column A drive company industry supply list (that will be in paragraph form)  in column J. Here is an example:

Column:
ABC level 1
ABC level 2
ABC Levels Elementary
ABC Levels Advanced
BCD Level 4
BCD Level All
BCD Level Intermediate
(continued until infinity..)
XYZ Company Level 12

**If Level 1-6 or Elementary: Input >** 
Eucalyptus is one of three similar genera that are commonly referred to as "eucalypts",

**If level Intermediate: Input>** 
Tree sizes follow the convention of:

**If Level Advanced: Input >** 
A mature eucalyptus may take the form of a low shrub or a very large tree. The species can be divided into three main habits and four size categories.

**If level all: Input >** 
Eucalyptus is one of three similar genera that are commonly referred to as "eucalypts"
 **+** 
Tree sizes follow the convention of:

**+** 
A mature eucalyptus may take the form of a low shrub or a very large tree. The species can be divided into three main habits and four size categories.

*eucalyptus copy used for example only and to educate us all on the eucalyptus plant of course.* ** changed the copy to shorter so we can more easily read the example**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8yr8t.png)

Thanks so much!
Kalina

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say if I have a `Sheet2` with data like the picture showing below:

[image]

My `Sheet1` should look like this:

[image]

There are at least two ways to accomplish your goal:

1. `VLOOKUP` (show in `column C`, `Matching 1`):

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!$A$2:$D$8,2,0)&", "&VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!$A$2:$D$8,3,0)&", "&VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!$A$2:$D$8,4,0)
```

The `VLOOKUP` just repeated three times to concatenate the first name, last name and the email.

2. `INDEX/MATCH` (show in `column D`, `Matching 2`):

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!$A$1:$D$8,MATCH(A2,Sheet2!$A$1:$A$8,0),2)&", "&INDEX(Sheet2!$A$1:$D$8,MATCH(A2,Sheet2!$A$1:$A$8,0),3)&", "&INDEX(Sheet2!$A$1:$D$8,MATCH(A2,Sheet2!$A$1:$A$8,0),4)
```

Similar to `VLOOKUP` to repeat three times.

Hope this helps and let me know if you have any question.

Comment: Hi there @ian0411 !Thanks so much that was a lot of help. I tried your formulas by replicating your sample data and got the results but something happened when I tried to do it with my work data it wouldn't work. I kept on getting an N/A error. I can't share it because it's for work. Do you know why this is happening? Also do I just take out the & & signs to have the data populate in separate columns not one together?

Comment: I will guess the data is not there.  In that case, you can wrap an `IFERROR` around the formula such as `=IFERROR([the formula you want],"[empty or the message you want to show]")`.  Also, I don't know how you want to show your result and therefore I had the `& &`.  Of course you can remove them or let me know how you want your end result be look like and I can try to come up something for you.

Comment: is it possible to use a similar formula to populate paragraph text in another column if the company name contains certain text or letters? Say the company titles are various and long but each contain adjectives that can help distinguish their industry or years of experience, then is it possible to make another column including 10+ possible conditions to fill out different paragraphs depending on the conditions met?

Comment: I believe so.  You can edit your question and expected results with some examples.  I will help you out.

Comment: @Kalina Nikolova, do you mind insert some data or pic so it will be easier to grasp?

Comment: Hi there just uploaded a screenshot!

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do for your part 2:

[image]

For example you have setup a table to show different levels and descriptions (`Column D and E`).  And you want to find the description under `column B` from the given company info on `column A`.  Here is the formula you want to enter in `cell B2` and copy/drag down.

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-FIND("Level",A2)+1),$D$2:$E$11,2,0),"Please verify company name")
```

What this does is first, use `RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-FIND("Level",A2)+1)` to find which level keyword inside the company name.  Then use `VLOOKUP` to look the matching level and grab the description from `column E`.  I also added an `IFERROR` just in case someone entered an incorrect name.  You can change that message output to anything you like.  Hope this will solve your problem and let me know if you have any question.

Comment: Thank you - I'm going to test this out and see if I can get the same result as you. The picture I uploaded above is with  me manually filling out the text for the Supply List. To note, my biggest challenge is that I don't have a level column already populated and there is 2000 rows+, so creating a level column by hand would be too tedious and time consuming.

Comment: If you already have the data of that list but they are just repetitive, you can  copy that whole column into some other sheet, and do `Data > Remove Duplicates` and that way you will have the good ones to use.  Just append the Level column before it and you are good to go.

Comment: I didn't understand your last comment. Can you please elaborate/ rephrase?

Comment: Hi there - thanks this worked really well with the example from above but not exactly with my document. How do I modify the FIND formula to search for the grade level anywhere within the company name? For example not just ABC +1 but what if the company name said Level 1 ABC or 1st ABC ? Then I would only want to search for the 1 but also exclude the possibility of it being 10 or 11?

Comment: SO is not really a code for me service.  Therefore, you should use these examples as a guideline and adapt to the way you want.  Personally, it is okay for me to help you out but I will need to know exactly how your data is structured and designed.  And also how you want the results look like.  If you can upload a pic with all that info (type out if needed), I will update my answer just to fit your need.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest putting data info on each tab into a tables, and then using an Index-Match or a vlookup to pull the data from the other table that matches. It's hard to give an exact answer without an image/example.

Comment: How do I properly use the index or match formulas though? I kept on getting errors.

I'll share a screenshot on Monday.